# How can I add localStorage and Json(parse, stringify) to my JS project?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a random password generator app using JavaScript. I want to add localStorage to store the passwords that were generated but have no idea on how to do it.

I've tried using a localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem but I cannot get it working.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand , I'll leave the JS code down below.

Thanks.

Comment: The password is already a string; you don't have to stringify it.

Comment: Yes true, and how would i localStorage that?

Comment: Added html to snippet

Comment: Unfortunately, snippets don't support `localStorage`. Perhaps you could explain a bit more about what you mean by: "I cannot get it working". `console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage, null, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add localStorage to store the passwords that were generated

Your code is correct. When you click on "copiar" button, the click event handler is called which stores the password to localStorage. If you are using Chrome, you can check the Application tab in Chrome Dev tools to check that it is being stored.
[image]